# Formatting any cell referenced in a Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have two sheets, one with formulas pulling data from the second. I need to create a macro or some conditional format to highlight the cell green if the data was pulled from the second sheet. sheet two is raw data and sheet one is a break down of the data into different tables.

To Clarify my Queston, I have a Raw Data Sheet and a Income Sheet. The Income Sheet has formulas that pull data from the table in the raw data sheet. What I am trying to do is: **Highlight all the cells in the raw data sheet that get called/referenced in the income statement sheet**; that way, I know if something in the raw data sheet was not used or included in the income sheet. The Formula in the Income Statement that I pull data from the Raw Data sheet is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A643, 'Raw Data'!$A:$N, 4, FALSE)), "-", VLOOKUP($A643, 'Raw Data'!$A:$N, 4, FALSE))
```

The A column has a specific code that comes up in the Raw Data Sheet in the same column. I hope this info helps.
Thank you! I found this code below, but do not know how to adjust it to check on a separate sheet.

```
Sub Button5_Click()

'PLEASE EDIT THIS FIRST BIT. 

Dim row As Integer
row = 1    ' THE STARTING ROW IN YOUR EXCEL SHEET

Dim numberOfRows As Integer
numberOfRows = 5    'THE TOTAL NUMBER OF ROWS YOUR WORKSHEET HAS

Dim columnWithFormula As String
columnWithFormula = "E"    ' THE COLUMN WHERE THE FORMULAs ARE (I suspect you are using B if your example is accurate))

Dim colourIndex As Integer
colourIndex = 26     ' WHAT COLOUR TO HIGHLIGHT COLUMNS. GOOGLE VBa COLOR INDEX

'AND STOP EDITING :)

For row = 1 To numberOfRows

If range(columnWithFormula & row).Value <> "" Then

   Dim result As String

   result = range(columnWithFormula & row).Formula

   result = Replace(result, "(", " ")
   result = Replace(result, ")", " ")
   result = Replace(result, "-", " ")
   result = Replace(result, "+", " ")
   result = Replace(result, "*", " ")
   result = Replace(result, "/", " ")
   result = Replace(result, "=", " ")
   result = Replace(result, ",", " ")

   Dim cells() As String
   cells = Split(Trim(result), " ")

   For j = 0 To UBound(cells)
    range(cells(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = colourIndex
   Next j

End If

Next row


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SU! Just a note, it's *Excel*, not *Excell*, ...please avoid tags in titles. =)

Comment: @Raystafarian: It looks like he did a lot of research, found a solution that's close, and is now stuck on modifying the code to reflect separate worksheets, which he say, "but do not know how".  If every problem requires puttering until it's either solved or the person is driven to drink, we wouldn't have very many questions to help people with.

Comment: @fixer1234 if you find code online and don't try to do anything to it, what is the question? "here's someone else's work, make it work for me"? It's one thing if you found snippets and tried them, or ran the recorder and need help, but this is just too broad for me. I didn't downvote.

Comment: You added a very interesting twist that is sort of the opposite of what the original wording implied.  A critical question that affects the scope and difficulty (even whether it's answerable on SU): Is every reference on the Income Statement sheet a direct reference to a single cell (like 'Raw Data'!A5)?  If not, would the only exceptions be a range (like 'Raw Data'!A2:A10)?  Are there any named ranges or table references used?  Are there any indirect references, where the cell reference is built using a string and references to current values of other cells?

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish would require someone writing a mini-application in VBA to do it as your describe.  It's way beyond the scope of a Super User question.  The basic function is verifying that all of the data is used.  Make that the objective, rather than doing it in a specific way (that happens to be difficult).  Let people suggest other approaches that are doable.

Answer (score 2):

An approach with conditional formatting, without any VBA, involves the function FormulaText() which is available in Excel 2013 and up.

Create a conditional formula with a format that checks if the name of a specific sheet exists in the formula. For example, if a sheet is called "raw data", then this formula will highlight cells that refer to that sheet.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("raw data",FORMULATEXT(A2)))
```

[image]

This can also be applied to checking if a formula references an Excel Table, using structured references, where the sheet name does not feature in the formula, but the table name does.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RawDataTable",FORMULATEXT(A2)))
```

Using different conditional formulas for different sheets, this can be a very effective way of quickly highlighting data that does not originate in the current sheet.

Note: Theoretically, any (non-structured) reference to another sheet could be identified by the `!` sign after the sheet name in the reference, but sometimes, when creating formulas that go across sheets, a reference to a cell on the current sheet might also include the sheet name, so that approach should be used with caution.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot tomorrow. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, yeah, you changed the question completely days after my answer. Talking about moving goal posts.....